# how can angular navigate to www.google.com

Tags: angular

I am using angular 7 to navigate the app to https:www.google.com,

```
constructor( public router: Router ) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl("https://www.google.com");
}
```

but it gives me the error saying

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'https:'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'https:'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
```

any way to pass it around?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the router service to navigate to an external link.

You can use: `window.location.href = 'some-url'`